# Kendo UI: Place Grid Summary Values in Footer

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Using the Kendo UI Grid and MVC 4, I haven't been able to find a way to put summary totals (financial) at the bottom of the grid for select columns.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes indeed! check [DataSource Aggregate](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#aggregate%20array%20%20objectdefault%29).

Example:

```js
var stocksDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport:{
        read:function (options) {
        }
    },
    schema   :{
        model:{
            fields:{
                name :{ type:"string" },
                price:{ type:"number" }
            }
        }
    },
    aggregate:[
        { field:"price", aggregate:"sum" }
    ],
    pageSize :10
});
```

I have defined a `DataSource` with two fields: the items `name` and `price`. I want to totalize the `price` so I defined an `aggregate` for `price` and what I'm going to do is `sum` (you can also `min`, `max`, `average` and `count`).

Then in the `Grid` when I define the columns I write:

```js
columns    :[
    { field:"name", title:"Product" },
    { field:"price", title:"Price", footerTemplate:"Sum: #= sum # " }
],
```

And that's it!

Comment: How would that be done in an @Html.Kendo().Grid(Model) helper?

Comment: Let me see if I can type as SO comment this:

    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Aggregates(aggregates => { aggregates.Add(p => p.price).Sum(); } ) )

And the column:

Columns(columns => { columns.Bound(p => p.name); columns.Bound(p => p.price) .ClientFooterTemplate("Sum: #=sum#"); })

Comment: I'm glad it has been useful!!

Comment: @OnaBai I would just like to know if you can answer the last part of question as well?

Comment: @JohanJvRensburg, which is the latest part of the question that is missing?

Comment: @OnaBai "for select columns" is the last part I'm revering to.

Comment: @JohanJvRensburg not sure what is the problem, my answer only computer total for column `Price`, you can do the same with whichever column.

Comment: @OnaBai what I'm trying to ask if how do you do this for selected rows I see that I misread the question. What I would like to know if how to do this for selected rows.

Comment: @JohanJvRensburg It might be done but this is a completely new question. Maybe you should post a different question.